# GridView Image Width and Height

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I have a `GridView` with `ImageView`s in it. Current, the images (which are all portrait orientation) are scaled down so that they fit the height of the rows, even though this leaves a large amount of empty space around the sides of the image. I've attempted adjusting the `ImageView` `ScaleType`:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

`CENTER_CROP` and `FIT_XY` both provide seamless edge-to-edge images, however they either stretch/compress or crop the image to the size of the containing cell in the grid. How can I scale the cell larger to accommodate the height of the image when the width fills the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property I was missing here was `adjustViewBounds`. Setting this to `true` makes the `ImageView` scale to fit the image it contains.

Done in XML:

```
<ImageView adjustViewBounds="true">
```

Done in Java:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true):
```